# Using Ajax to run a php script to change a session variable for a Login System

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http

I am creating a website with a login system for a university assignment. the method to do this i have created is have a a php page (the main page) have a section on the top that checks for a session variable for the user:

```
<?php
    // open the session
    session_start();
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    // check for existing user
    if(isset($_SESSION['User'])){
        $isUser = true;
        $userName = $_SESSION['userName'];
    }else{
        $isUser = false;
    }
?}
```

There is more to this but the rest is just functions that use the session to add appropriate fields (login section/logged in confirmation) this works fine.

In order to change the session variable a login confirmation function is used (very long script to check against database, also works perfectly) and at the end of the login check if correct changes the session variable like so:

```
//Start the session
session_start();
$arrUser = $result[0];
$_SESSION['User'] = $arrUser[0];
$_SESSION['userName'] = $arrUser[1];
return true;
```

this works, if loaded in a separate page (changes the session variable and adjusts adjusts the page to confirm session has changed, only if url in manually opened with variables). however by attempting to run the php using ajax:

```
function Login(){

    var Username = document.getElementById("Username");
    var Password = document.getElementById("Password");

    if(Username.value != "" && Password.value != ""){

        URL = "https://localhost/CAB230/Login.php?username=" + Username.value +
            "&password=" + Password.value;

        httpGetAsync(URL, function(response){
            if(response){
                location.reload();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Username").style.background = "red";
                document.getElementById("Password").style.background = "red";
            }
        });
    } else {
        window.alert("Username and Password fields must both be filled out");
    }
}


function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback){

    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

results in true being return and the page being reloaded, but the session variable don't change as the login section loads instead of the logged in confirmation section.

This is very confusing because running this ajax on my laptop changes the session variable, however on my PC this doesn't work.

Comment: `and at the end of the login check if correct changes the session variable like so:` session_start needs to be used before any output is generated server side.  Usually session_start() would be your first line of code on every page you call involving a session.  Put session_start at the top of your page and try again.

Comment: That first block of code is at the top of every page, i do call session_start() before everything. when include a function to check if session has changed so variables have. it only says the variable has changed after i open the url ajax is calling in another tab

Comment: Any white spaces from the start of the file to the session_start may also cause you problems.  The server can not send anything prior to the session_start.